# Transaction killed when insert permission denied and ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm sure it's intended behavior, I'm just trying to understand it better. I am seeing that a transaction is set to null when:

1. ANSI_WARNINGS are off
2. An insert is attempted on a table for which insert permissions have been denied

That's fine. What seems strange to me is that if I turn ANSI_WARNINGS ON (remove first condition above), the transaction is not set to null.

Why is that? Let me know if there's some ANSI_WARNINGS documentation that I've missed that would explain this.

Code to reproduce issue:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
public class Program
{
    //CREATE TABLE Junk( Name varchar(12) )
    //DENY INSERT ON Junk to someUser

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool ansi_warnings_off = false;
        int result;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=dbServerName;Initial Catalog=dbName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=someUser;Password=somePassword;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                cmd.Transaction = trans;

                if (ansi_warnings_off)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF";
                    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("===Result of setting ansi_warnings off = " + result);
                }

                try
                {                   
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Junk(Name) VALUES ('test')";
                    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("===Result of insert = " + result);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("===Exception for insert = " + e.Message);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("===Transaction is null? " + (cmd.Transaction == null));
            }
            conn.Close();
        }//using
    }//main
}
```

Output when ansi_warnings_off = true:

```
===Result of setting ansi_warnings off = -1
===Exception for insert = The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'Junk', database 'dbName', schema 'dbo'.
===Transaction is null? True
```

Output when ansi_warnings_off = false:

```
===Exception for insert = The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'Junk', database 'dbName', schema 'dbo'.
===Transaction is null? False
```

**Edit:** to simplify, here's some T-SQL that reproduces the issue too if you just want to run it in SQL Server Management Studio.

```sql
--------do this as sa---------
CREATE TABLE Junk( Name varchar(12) )
INSERT INTO Junk(Name) VALUES ('original')
DENY INSERT ON Junk to dbUser
---------------------------------

--now do the next two as dbUser

-----update is not attempted----
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO Junk(Name) VALUES ('new')
update Junk SET Name = 'updated' where Name = 'original'
COMMIT TRAN
--------------------------------

--------update is done------
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO Junk(Name) VALUES ('new')
update Junk SET Name = 'updated' where Name = 'original'
COMMIT TRAN
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I posted this question on [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/82e0afa5-1657-4055-a565-172289d30615/ansiwarnings-off-deny-permissions-transaction-killed-why) too, got a hint of a reason: XACT_ABORT setting. Seems like some buggy behavior where ANSI_WARNINGS and XACT_ABORT meet (ANSI_WARNINGS can affect XACT_ABORT behavior), I created a [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/796779/xact-abort-off-ansi-warnings-off-transaction-rolled-back-upon-first-error-unexpectedly) issue, which probably will go nowhere.